# Standardize Outlook Contacts Format

Tags: microsoft-outlook, contacts

I have Outlook syncing with my cell phone (WinMo 6.1) and vice versa. Everything works fine, but my numbers are all in different formats.  I have some contacts with numbers of 5555551234, some are 555.555.1234, some are (555) 555-1234, some are 555-555-1234, etc.  I don't really care how it's displayed, because they all dial fine on my phone.  But I want to clean them up so they all look the same.  Any easy ways to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [this](http://www.outlook-stuff.com/lang-en/products/contacts/228-formatnumbers.html) is helpful. It´s a Freeware Tool called FormatNumbers. It´s especially made for your Problem.

Comment: That looks like what I need, but the problem isn't worth 19.90 € to me...

Answer (score 1):

Can you get the numbers out of it in some readable format, change them and then parse again? I think Outlook uses CSV for export/sync (at least for events, not so sure about contacts), you could read that into excel and use some simple string manipulation formulas, then import the result back.